# Using Autoselect to populate form fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to create a php form which uses autoselect to select an item, and from that selection, it populates the price input field and from that, populate the subtotal and total fields.

I have a table called "accessories" which has the following fields:

accessories_id | accessories_name | accessories_price

I can get the first autoselect to work but Im not sure where to go from there. Im ok with php but with Javascript I am an utter novice and don't know where to start.

**html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Autocomplete</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#accessories_name").autocomplete({
source:'getautocomplete.php',
minLength:1
});
});

$("#accessories_name").autocomplete({
  source:'getautocomplete.php',
  minLength:1,
  change: function( event, ui ) {}
});


$( "#accessories_name" ).on( "autocompletechange", function( event, ui ) {
   $("accessories_price").val(ui.item.value); //sets price with the value from selected accessory
   // [...] other fields logic
} );

$( "#quantity" ).change(function() {
   var subtotal = $("#accessories_price").val() * $("#quantity").val(); //don't forget to verify if are numbers
   $("#subtotal").val(subtotal);
})
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="">
  Name : <input type="text" size="40" id="accessories_name" name="accessories_name" />
  Price: <input type="text" size="30" id="accessories_price" name="accessories_price" />
  Quantity: <input type="text" size="30" id="quantity" name="quantity" />
  Subtotal: <input type="text" size="30" id="subtotal" name="subtotal" />
  <br />
  Name : <input type="text" size="40" id="accessories_name" name="accessories_name" />
  Price: <input type="text" size="30" id="accessories_price" name="accessories_price" />
  Quantity: <input type="text" size="30" id="quantity" name="quantity" />
  Subtotal: <input type="text" size="30" id="subtotal" name="subtotal" />
  <br />
  Total: <input type="text" size="40" id="accessories_total" name="accessories_total" />
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

**php file**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "password");
mysql_select_db("db");
$term=$_GET["term"];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accessories WHERE accessories_description LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER by accessories_description");
$json=array();
while($accessories=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     $json[]=array(
                'value'=>$accessories["accessories_name"],
                'label'=>$accessories["accessories_name"]." - ".$accessories["accessories_id"]
                );
}
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to initialize the `change` callback by adding it in the `autocomplete`:

```
   $("#accessories_name").autocomplete({
      source:'getautocomplete.php',
      minLength:1,
      change: function( event, ui ) {} //add this to your current autocomplete
   });
```

After you need to create a listener for the `change` callback so it will be called once an option is selected in the autocomplete field. Within this listener you will have your code to update the price and other fields:

```
   $( "#accessories_name" ).on( "autocompletechange", function( event, ui ) {
       $("accessories_price").val(ui.item.value); //sets price with the value from selected accessory
       // [...] other fields logic
   } );
```

For fields other than `autocomplete` you can use the jquery `.change()` method as in ´#quantity´ case for example:

```
   $( "#quantity" ).change(function() {
       var subtotal = $("#accessories_price").val() * $("#quantity").val(); //don't forget to verify if are numbers
       $("#subtotal").val(subtotal);
   })
```

Add this code with the changes you need for your logic inside the `$(document).ready({})` event,
and be careful with the IDs from second and other acessories

Comment: Thanks @G.Mendes but it still didn't seem to work, I have updated the code above.

Comment: try actually updating the first `.autocomplete()` with the changes I suggested instead of adding a new block, also you have the second accessory block with same IDs of first yet. The javascript code needs to be inside `$(document).ready({})` event as well, reply back if any probs